# What does the . (period) symbol reference in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

As it says on the tin, what does the `.` (period) symbol reference in elisp? I can't find a variable reference in the Emacs documentation, and Google is (unsurprisingly) unhelpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The period is the `cons` operator and not a symbol in the lisp sense.  E.g.:

```
(setq nums '(1 . 2))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(setq nums (cons 1 2))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm coming from Clojure where there are no infix operators and I assumed elisp was the same. Good to know.

Comment: See also `C-h i g (elisp) Dotted Pair Notation RET`. I think Clojure is something of an exception in this regard -- my understanding is that most lisps recognise this notation.

Comment: @mybuddymichael `.` is not an infix operator like those in languages with infix syntax — for example, you can't write `(foo . bar . baz)`. Instead, `(form1 . form2)` is basic syntax for creating conses, similar to how `(form1 form2 form3...)` is basic syntax for creating lists in both clojure and elisp. The difference is that in elisp, `(1 2 3)` is syntactic sugar for `(1 . (2 . (3 . nil)))`. It is not immediately obvious why clojure chose to omit syntax for cons creation.

Comment: Does Clojure have conses? I thought it had lists and pairs as distinct things (but, I haven't really looked deeply into it).

Comment: Yes, Clojure has conses and the [`cons`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/cons) function, but it doesn't support the dotted-pair notation.